# Updating entity with enums not removing old entries in ef code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a teacher entity that's not updating my 'YogaClasses' table correctly, it's writing new values to 'YogaClasses' but not deleting/modifying old values. To fix this do I need to restructure my controller to modify the old values or do I need to modify my repository to delete old values before I insert new ones??

```
public class Teacher
{
   // other members...
   public virtual ICollection<YogaClass> YogaClasses { get; set; } 
}
```

YogaClass object here with an enum in it.

```
public class YogaClass
{
    public int YogaClassId { get; set; }
    public YogaStyle YogaStyle { get; set;}
}
```

YogaStyle enum here.

```
public enum YogaStyle
{
    [Display(Name = "Beginner Anusara")]
    BeginnerAnusara,
    [Display(Name = "Intermediate Anusara")]
    IntermediateAnusara,
    // more members here...
}
```

If YogaClasses have already been added by a teacher (multiselect dropdown list) it will look like this.

[image]

Now lets say the teacher goes in and deselects some of her previous selections and adds new ones. When I update, entity framework doesn't remove/delete/modify the previous entries, it just writes new ones like this. You can see the teacher removed 1,4,6 and added 52,53,54,55.

[image]

In my controller, before I 'UpdateOrInsert()' in my repository, I just set all the classes selected by the teacher here

```
 public ActionResult Edit(EditTeacherViewModel viewModel)
 {  
     // other code here...
     teacher.YogaClasses = GetSelectedClasses(viewModel);
     teacherRepository.InsertOrUpdate(teacher);
 }
```

Here is the GetSelectedClasses method

```
 private ICollection<YogaClass> GetSelectedClasses(EditTeacherViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ICollection<YogaClass> classes = new Collection<YogaClass>();
        int[] selectedClasses = viewModel.SelectedYogaStyles;
        foreach (int selectedClass in selectedClasses)
        {
            YogaClass yogaClass = new YogaClass();
            yogaClass.YogaStyle = (YogaStyle)selectedClass;
            classes.Add(yogaClass);
        }
        return classes;
    }
```

And here is my 'UpdateOrInsert()' from my repo.

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(Teacher teacher)
    {
        if (teacher.TeacherId == default(int))
        {
            // New entity
            context.Teachers.Add(teacher);
        }
        else
        {
            // Existing entity
            context.Entry(teacher).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The "old" entries need to be in a "Deleted" state before they will be removed from the DB. Replacing the collection doesn't do that.

Comment: Does that mean I should delete my teacher object in my repo before I perform a 'InsertOrUpdate()'?

Comment: Did you found the answer to this question ? I'm facing it today (

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the old entries to EntityState.Deleted. I would make this more explicit on the server side e.g have a delete ActionResult. This should be more testable as well. Also you want to delete the YogaClass entities so you should have a controller for this action perhaps? No reason you cant call through to this from your Update/Insert for teacher ActionResult.

Update in reposne to question:
You need to undertsand that you are deleting the YogaClass records not the teacher records. Example:

```
var teacher = new Teacher();
teacher.id = 0;
teacher.Yogaclasses = new List<YogaClass>();
context.Teachers.Add(teacher);
context.SaveChanges
```

We know have a teacher with no yoga classes. In the db there will be one row in the Teacher table with an id of 1.

You add in the YogaClass entries. and you link them to a teacher.

```
var yogaClass = new YogaClass();
yogaClass.yogastyle = 1;
yogaClass.teacherId = 1:
```

save changes etc etc.

Once the details are all saved to the db when you retrieve the Teacher with Id of 1 from the db the context will populate the YogaClasses for you. Lets say you did this for 10 YogaClasses and they have Ids 1 through 10;

If I then proveide this list to the client and they remove YogaClasses with Id 1 and 2 when I receive the Teacher object back to my update method I can:

Retrieve the current database object from the context (this will still have 10 YogaClass items in the list);
I can the iterate over the YogaClass items in the context objext and check if the ViewModel object has the same records. For any items that dont exist on the ViewModel but do exist on the context object they need to be deleted.

I know I have two YogaClass entries (id 1 & 2) that need to be deleted. This is a seperate concern (think SOLID always!!). I could expose in my repository a DeleteYogaClass(YogaClass yogaClass) method or DeleteYogaClasses(IEnumerable yogaClasses)

for single YogaClass:

```
    try
    {
        context.YogaClasses.Remove(yogaClass);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
            "The YogaClass with an ID of '{0}' could not be deleted etc etc";
    }
```

for more than one class foreach and set all to deleted.

Comment: Can you please provide a little more detail? Where would I set this? Repository's InsertOrUpdate method or should I delete the teacher object first. I'm a little unsure about where this should take place.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I think you are misunderstanding how to manage the state of your context objects.

Comment: the problem I see here is that the list I'm passing to the client DOESN'T have the id from the yogaclass object in it. I'm passing a MultiSelectList(styles, "ID", "Name", selectedValues); Where ID is the enum index and Name is the name of the enum. So I'm not passing the YogaClassId into the client model object. Should I be? Can I? Can I pass it in the another overloaded MultSelectList?

Comment: Thats a different question but you could - some say never pass the id of your entites around on the client - think about security when you do this. Look at you YogaClass object. Your Yoga Style could be a unique constraint if the teacher cant duplicate this column. You could use this and the Teacher Id to find the record. If not then the Id is the only identifier and you should use this - or add a unique identifier element to your table. As I said this is a different question but to delete a record from a database you need to be able to find it and the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Well said @Luthervd, first clear your old entries before posting updated ones.

Comment: I tried adding a 'context.Entry(teacher.YogaClasses).State = EntityState.Deleted;' to my UpdateOrInsert() inside my repo but t hat threw an error.